# WebStorm - can I expand folder in sidebar in one click?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm

Can I just expand folder in one click like Atom and VSCode?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on those triangle-looking icons (that expand nodes in a tree)?

Comment: @LazyOne Sure I know that, but that's not convenient when there are many many folders.

Comment: `NumPad +` to expand single level, `Numpad *` to expand all levels. It can be seen (and re-mapped if needed) into `Settings -> Keymap`